# Making an on/off button with images

Tags: javascript

I have two images, sound_on.png and sound_off.png. Both have the same height and dimensions.

I would like to attach a JavaScript for the following action:

1. When the pressed images changes from sound_off.png to sound_on.png and the sound plays
2. When the button is pressed again it changes back from sound_on.png to sound_off.png and the sound stops with the onclick command

At the moment I have these lines of code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="playAudio();"><img src="images/general/sound-on.png" width="40" height="32"></a>
<a href="#" onClick="stopAudio();"><img src="images/general/sound-off.png" width="40" height="32"></a>
```

What code do I need to make them like the above example?

I have this part:

```
<style type="text/css">
.on {background-image:url url(images/general/sound-off.png)); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.off {background-image:url(images/general/sound-on.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
</style>
<script language="javascript">
function togglestyle(el){if(el.className == "on") {el.className="off";} else {el.className="on";}}
</script>
```

With this DIV for the button:

```
div id="onoff" class="playlist_btn"><img src="images/general/sound-off.png" width="50 height="50" onclick="togglestyle(onoff)"></div>
```

This makes the toggle, but I have no idea so far how to connect the onclick command to get the audio playing and to stop it again.

Could it be something like this?

```
function togglestyle(el){if(el.className == "on" onClick="playAudio()") {el.className="off" onClick"stopAudio()";} else {el.className="on";}}
```

Comment: Sorry i mean the images references that call the onClick commands

Comment: why two images instead of one? This seems the work for something like a toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the sound functions directly from your existing toggle function:

```
function togglestyle(el){

    if(el.className == "on") {
        el.className="off";
        stopAudio();
    }
    else {
        el.className="on";
        playAudio();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This script combined does the trick as well

```
<script>
function showHide(elementid){
if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
} else {
document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
}
}

function hideShow(elementid){
if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == ''){
document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
} else {
document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
}
}
</script>


<img id="on" src="images/general/sound-off.png" width="40" height="32" onClick="javascript:hideShow('on'); javascript:showHide('off'); javascript:playAudio()" alt="on">
<img id="off" src="images/general/sound-on.png" width="40" height="32" onClick="javascript:hideShow('off'); javascript:showHide('on')" style="display:none;" alt="off">
```

But i was wondering would there be a way to detect when the audio is finished playing and return to the off state and integrate a trird option, to pause the audio (with an pause image) and continue where the audio was left of? Any ideas?